# ProcessBuilder - Run bat file with arguments - spaces in path

Tags: java, windows, processbuilder

there are many questions at stackoverflow regarding the processbuilder and "spaces in path". I've tried many of them, but no one works for me.. lets state the problem:

Suppose the "dir" variable points to directory which exits:

```
URI outputURI = new URI(("file:///"+ dir)); 
            File f = new File(outputURI);

            for (final File fileEntry : f.listFiles()) {
                if(fileEntry.getName().equals("R.bat")){
                    dir = fileEntry.getAbsolutePath();

                }      
            }

            expr[0] = dir;//"\""+dir+"\"";
            expr[1] = "-e";
            expr[2] = "\"library(Rserve);Rserve("+(debug?"TRUE":"FALSE")+",args='"+rsrvargs+"')\"";
            expr[3] = "--no-save";
            expr[4] = "--slave";

            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(expr);
            pb.directory(f);
            p = pb.start();
```

If

```
dir = fileEntry.getAbsolutePath();
```

returns a path without a space, everything works fine. But if it contains a space, the process doesnt start. Quote the dir variable doesnt work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: escape the space in the path.

Comment: I've added the follow line: `dir = dir.replace(" ", "\\ ");` But it doesnt work. It produces an exception: cannot run program error=2 no such file or directory

Comment: try to use  getErrorStream on the process to see whats the error

Comment: one more thing. For cmd line args and program names which  have spaces you need to enclose them in quotes. try to print to console the whole command line which is being executed and they copy and try that manually.

Comment: That is the complete command: `"C:\pathwith space\R.bat" -e "library(Rserve);Rserve(FALSE,args='--no-save --slave')" --no-save --slave`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ProcessBuilder cannot run bat file with spaces in path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25377355/processbuilder-cannot-run-bat-file-with-spaces-in-path)