# ProcessBuilder cannot run bat file with spaces in path

Tags: java, batch-file

I have the following code segment to run a bat file:

```
String workingDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");

ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", 
"\"" + workingDir + File.separator + "midl.bat\"");

Process ddsBuildProc = pb.start();

ddsBuildProc.waitFor();
```

The workingDir includes spaces in the path. Eventhough I use quotes to enclose the workingDir+fileName string, the shell still splits the  workingDir and doesn't run the bat file. If a try and copy-paste-execute the bat file path string in the Windows command window manually, it works as expected. What can be the problem here?

Also, please do not close this question as duplicate because I tried all the solutions in the other questions with no success.

Comment: You don't need to quote the path.  You could also try using `ProcessBuilder#directory` to set the working directory for the executioin context

Comment: I added the quotes because I was unsuccessful without them. As expected, they don't alter the outcome.

Comment: `user.dir` is you current program execution context...does the `midl.bat` file exist within this directory???  Something like `System.out.println(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"), "midl.bat").exists());` should be able to tell you...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Don't quote commands in a command list, unless the command been executed expects it, this will just stuff things up
- `user.dir` is your programs current executing context...so it actually makes no sense to include it, you could just use `midl.bat` by itself (assuming the command exists within the current execution context)

I wrote a really simple batch file...

```
@echo off
dir
```

Which I put in my "C:\Program Files" directory, as I need a path with spaces and used....

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class RunBatch {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(
                        "cmd", "/c", "listme.bat"
        );
        pb.directory(new File("C:/Program Files"));
        pb.redirectError();
        try {
            Process process = pb.start();
            InputStreamConsumer.consume(process.getInputStream());
            System.out.println("Exited with " + process.waitFor());
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static class InputStreamConsumer implements Runnable {

        private InputStream is;

        public InputStreamConsumer(InputStream is) {
            this.is = is;
        }

        public static void consume(InputStream inputStream) {
            new Thread(new InputStreamConsumer(inputStream)).start();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            int in = -1;
            try {
                while ((in = is.read()) != -1) {
                    System.out.print((char) in);
                }
            } catch (IOException exp) {
                exp.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

To run it without any issues...

Comment: and if you have more than one space in a path in an overall command? but you can only set one working directory? such as `rsync /path with spaces/ /destination with spaces/`

Comment: @haventchecked How would you run it from the command line? It might still end up looking like `new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "rsync \"path with space\" \"destination with spaces\"")` but I would be questioning why you're executing this via `cmd` and not directly, but that's ne

Comment: thanks for the quick reply 5 years later! It would look like this from a terminal (running on macOS):  `rsync -avP --exclude=Music/ pixel:/data/data/com.arachnoid.sshelper/files/home/SDCard/ "/Volumes/home/encfs/personal/pictures/Pixel 2 XL"` ... I solved it by sending to the ProcessBuilder constructor each logical grouping of characters as one element in the List.  e.g. `["rsync", "-avP", "--exclude=Music/", ...]` with each path being a separate String in full with no escaping of any characters or spaces.  My problem initially was that I was building the string and splitting on whitespace.

Comment: The reason for executing via ProcessBuilder is that I have a yaml file that feeds into a Groovy script that manages all of my backups with multiple thread pools that run non-conflicting disks in parallel and conflicting disks sequentially for hopefully max overall throughput.

Comment: After reading this again, I think I had a tangential problem.  I'm not using `cmd` at all, but the question and answer did point me back to the documentation.