# Open exe is not working through Java

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to open an executable and my code compiles fine but still does not open the .exe and doesnt give me errors. This is the class that is started from my swing gui. What am i missing?

```
package kioskapplications;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.ProcessBuilder;

public class OpenSSH {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String folder = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Kiosk Applications\\Poderosa\\";
    String exe = "Poderosa.exe";

    ProcessBuilder p = new ProcessBuilder();
    p.command(folder + exe);
    p.start();
  }
}
```

Comment: Try using `int result = p.waitFor()` and see if the command returns an exit code (usually anything other than `0` means it failed for some reason).  You should also be reading the process output, as this can some times stall programs (if the output buffer is not read).  You could also change the process's working directory, using `ProcessBuilder#directory` to the same directory that the executable is in...

Comment: (for an example of reading the process's output stream, have a look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25377355/processbuilder-cannot-run-bat-file-with-spaces-in-path/25377564#25377564))

Comment: use try-catch on `p.start()` and remove `throws` declaration, what error code do you get?

Comment: @JClassic, what difference will this make?

Comment: @user2900314 nevermind, I thought throws declaration nullifies any error output

Comment: @MadProgrammer received a result of 1. Im going to try with the directory next. Could this possibly be a permissions issue?

Comment: See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and (continue to) use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the `ProcessBuilder`'s directory before giving it the command. Use the [directory(File directory)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#directory(java.io.File)) method on p to give it a working directory and then set the command with the `command(String... command)` method.