# java process builder with c not displaying results?

Tags: java, c

I'm attempting to call a C program through Java using process builder. Through Java, I'm going to compile the C program (which it does) and then runs it which it don't.

I'm expecting the terminal to show Result: 6 but nothings showing

Java program (main.java)

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;

public class main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException
    {
    //compile + run
    Process compile = new ProcessBuilder("gcc", "calculator.c").start(); 
    //delay program to allow ./a.out to create
    try 
        {
        Thread.sleep(1000);                 //1000 milliseconds is one second.
        } 
    catch(InterruptedException ex) 
        {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }

    Process execute = new ProcessBuilder("./a.out").start();
    }
}
```

C Program: (calculator.c)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  int a = 4;
  int b = 2;
  int c = a + b;
  printf("Result: %d \n", c);
}
```

Comment: You need to read the process's `Input/ErrorStream` in order to see what it outputted, something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25377355/processbuilder-cannot-run-bat-file-with-spaces-in-path/25377564#25377564) for example

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Tried looking at it and it seems puzzling! Do i need to add an entire new method in?

Comment: You just need to consume the `Input/ErrorStream`, I tend to use a `Thread` for this, as I like to call `Process#waitFor` so I can get exit code for the `Process`, but since this is a blocking call, I use a `Thread` to consume the stream as well, but that's just me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to...

1. Read the `Input/ErrorStream` of the process, this way, you know what they have outputted.
2. Use `Process#waitFor` to determine when a `Process` has completed, using things like `Thread.sleep` are just asking for trouble.

Because you need to consume the `Input/ErrorStream` of two processes, a simply thing to do is to write a method which can do that for you, so you don't need to duplicate code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("gcc", "calculator.c");
        pb.redirectErrorStream(true);

        Process compile = pb.start();
        consume(compile.getInputStream());

        int result = compile.waitFor();
        if (result == 0) {

            pb = new ProcessBuilder("./a.out");
            pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
            Process execte = pb.start();
            consume(execte.getInputStream());

            System.out.println("Program exited with " + execte.waitFor());

        } else {

            System.err.println("Compiler exited with " + result);

        }
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException exp) {
        exp.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static String consume(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(64);
    int in = -1;
    while ((in = is.read()) != -1) {
        result.append(result);
        // Technquially, you don't need this, but I like to have it as a check
        System.out.print((char) in);
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```