# ProcessBuilder with dynamic path (possibly with spaces)

Tags: java, file-io, processbuilder

I'm trying to run an external executable from my Java app. It resides in a package of that app, but the path to that app may vary, and may contain spaces. I have tried:

```
String broker = MqttServerInterface.class.getResource("broker/mosquitto.exe").getPath();

System.out.println(broker);            
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(broker,"-p",port);            

server = pb.start();
```

which works fine on paths without spaces. However, when there are spaces, it gives CreateProcess error=267, the directory name is invalid.

I have rewrote the code, according to suggestions here: [ProcessBuilder cannot run bat file with spaces in path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25377355/processbuilder-cannot-run-bat-file-with-spaces-in-path):

```
String brokerDir = MqttServerInterface.class.getResource("broker").getPath();            
System.out.println(brokerDir);

ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("mosquitto.exe","-p",port);
pb.directory(new File(brokerDir));
pb.redirectError();

server = pb.start();
```

but now, I still get error 267 with spaces in the path and error 2 (the system cannot find the file specified) without. What is a proper approach to run an executable from Java?

Comment: This is quite strange to begin with to have an "external" executable within your classpath. Are you sure you didn't mean to get it from the `PATH` environment variable instead?

Comment: @fge Well, I'm quite new to Java, so I don't know the best practices, but I want to have that executable to ship with my Java app, possibly in one package. I also see no reason why should I add to `PATH` something that will probably be used just by my application. Although, if there is any better place to store that executable than classpath, please suggest.

Comment: Could you show what `System.out.println(broker);` actually displays?

Comment: @Lolo it displays: `/N:/dropbox/Dropbox/projects/robot%202.0/prophio%203/prophio3/build/classes/com/trobot/prophio3/broker/mosquitto.exe`

Comment: So, do I take it that this is a native app?

Comment: Ah, so in fact it looks like a URL-encoded URI, which is not a file path. See the `%20` in there, which replace the spaces? Can you try replacing them with actual spaces with `broker = broker.replace("%20", " ");`?

Comment: @fge Application I try to run is multiplaform app (http://mosquitto.org/download/), but currently I would like to run just a Windows distribution of it.

Comment: @Lolo It worked! If you post it as an answer, I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As you posted in a comment, the result of `System.out.println(broker);` displays the following:

```
/N:/dropbox/Dropbox/projects/robot%202.0/prophio%203/prophio3/build/classes/com‌​/trobot/prophio3/broker/mosquitto.exe
```

This looks like a URL-encoded URI, which is not a file path, as indicated by the occurrences of `%20` in it. One way to fix this is to replace them with actual spaces, for instance like this:

```
broker = broker.replace("%20", " ");
```

Answer (score 0):

`getResource("res")` returns `URI` which is not a file reference, and `getPath` returns an URLencoded string of that `URI` and it is a wrong way to manually replace all special symbols. So let java find the right path for that `URI` by itself

```
URL brokerURI = MqttServerInterface.class.getResource("broker/mosquitto.exe");
Path pathToBroker = Paths.get(brokerURI.toURI());    
String brokerCommand = pathToBroker.toString();
```