# "Program Files" command intern not found CMD

Tags: java, cmd, processbuilder

I use java to excute a command line to create a database, i get an error when i excute this piece of code:

```
private final String POSTGRES_PATH = "\"C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\9.3\\bin\\psql.exe\"";
private final String DATA_BASE = "bd_name";

private void creerDataBase() {
    String command = this.POSTGRES_PATH + " -U postgres -d postgres -c \"CREATE DATABASE " + this.DATA_BASE + "\"";
    System.out.println("command = " + command);
    String creerBDD = executerCommande(command);
    System.out.println("Resultat : " + creerBDD);
}

public String executerCommande(String command) {
    String line;
    String resultat = "";
    try {
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", command);
        builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process p = builder.start();
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        while (true) {
            line = r.readLine();
            if (line == null) {
                break;
            }
            resultat += line + "\n";
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception = " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return resultat;
}
```

I get this result:

```
command = "C:\Program Files PostgreSQL\9.3\bin\psql.exe"\ -U postgres -d postgres -c "CREATE DATABASE bd_name"
```

and this error:

```
'C:\Program' n'est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne
```

This mean that Program is not an intern command.

but when i excute this command in CMD it work fine?

Is there any way to Build this Path because the ProcessBuilder not recognize `C:\Program Files`

Comment: it show me that the path is not recognized?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ProcessBuilder cannot run bat file with spaces in path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25377355/processbuilder-cannot-run-bat-file-with-spaces-in-path)

Comment: @A_Di-Matteo your exemple is about bat i dont need bat

Comment: what did you mean @Aaron can you provide an exemple or explain it more?

Comment: @YoucefLaidani the example answers your question though, check how it is solved, setting the Programs Files via the `directory` method rather than  as a full path command

Comment: I believe you could transform your pathes to the DOS format to get rid of the spaces. Check [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051088/how-to-get-dos-path-instead-of-windows-path) to learn how, and try to run the resulting path instead of the original one

Comment: @Aaron this is work with me thank you soooooo much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't run `cmd.exe` if you want to run a separate binary program.
`cmd.exe` is for scripts like `*.cmd` or `*.bat`

With `cmd.exe` you have to pass your command as an argument of CMD, and you should manage all OS-specific pitfalls like long paths with whitespaces, quotes inside qoutes etc.

Instead, you had better run `psql` itself.
The [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) takes a command and all the arguments as a list of separate strings. And `ProcessBuilder` is clever enough to do all the necessary magic with quotes and whitespaces by itself.

And take attention to the list of arguments - shells separate arguments by whitespaces, while `psql` might recognize the sequence of strings as a single argument.
We may assume that `-U postgress` is a single argument for `psql`, but for shell (`cmd.exe` in our case) these are two separate arguments - `-U` and `postgress`, so we should pass them to the `ProcessBuilder` separately

So the better way to run `psql` is to run it directly, something like that:

```
 new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\9.3\\bin\\psql.exe", 
                    "-U", "postgres", 
                    "-d", "postgres", 
                    "-c", "\"CREATE DATABASE " + this.DATA_BASE + "\"");
```

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution would be to remove the path (with spaces) from your constant field and use the [`directory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#directory(java.io.File)) method:

> Sets this process builder's working directory. Subprocesses subsequently started by this object's `start()` method will use this as their working directory. The argument may be `null` -- this means to use the working directory of the current Java process, usually the directory named by the system property `user.dir`, as the working directory of the child process.

Changing your code to:

```
private final String POSTGRES_DIR = "C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\9.3\\bin\\"
private final String POSTGRES_COMMAND = "psql.exe";

....

ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", command).directory(new File(POSTGRES_DIR));
.....
```

Comment: Thank you @A_Di-Matteo but i think something is not clear in your code first POSTGRES_DIR not a String should be Directory and my command is **-U postgres -d postgres -c \"CREATE DATABASE " + this.DATA_BASE + "\"** so this is not clear at all for me

Comment: @YoucefLaidani right, the code was just a sample to show how to restructure the existing one, not meant to be a full replacement (it is incomplete anyway). The main point was to use the `directory` method to set the current working directory: it should have solved your issue concerning the directory path with spaces.

Comment: thank you @A_Di-Matteo i will try it and infome you if it work thank you anyway so much

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for @Aaron his idea helps me so i solved this problem using this:

```
private final String POSTGRES_PATH = "C:\\PROGRA~1\\PostgreSQL\\9.3\\bin\\psql.exe";
```

this `C:\\PROGRA~1` inteed of this: `C:\\Program Files`

Comment: This is a dirty warkaround, but it is a working workaround. For those who are too lazy to read the documentation :)

Comment: what did you mean @Denis Kurochkin ?

Comment: It means that you shouldn't run one standalone program via another when you can run the first program directly.

Comment: With `cmd.exe` you forced to use a lot of workarounds, and that one is the only one you have found, but there are more which you don't know about. What will you do if the path is changed to another long one? Do you know how to get DOS-like path of your file? Will you add to documentation of your product instructions "how to get DOS-like path"? What will admin who is installing your app say about you if you demand him to put in configuration file DOS-like path instead of normal human-readable one?

Comment: Thank you @DenisKurochkin i understand now, so i will use your solution, thank you any way

Answer (score 0):

What you could try is instead of the space between program and files is %20 or \s.
So like:

`command = "C:\\Program%20Files\\PostgreSQL\\9.3\\bin\\psql.exe"`

or
`command = "C:\\Program\sFiles\\PostgreSQL\\9.3\\bin\\psql.exe"`

I hope one of them works for you, please let me know

EDIT: use double \ to get it to recognize the \