# Launch CMD command with spaces with JAVA

Tags: java, cmd, processbuilder

I want to excute in CMD with ProcessBuilder and here's my code :

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(
            "cmd /c start C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe --headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf javaGen.pdf  file:///C:/Users/User/Desktop/template/template2.html");
pb.start();
```

But I keep getting :

```
Cannot run program "cmd /c start C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf javaGen.pdf  file:///C:/Users/User/Desktop/template/template2.html": CreateProcess error=2, file not found
```

And I'm sure about chrome.exe and template2.html that they're in there respective paths.

***EDIT***

I also tried this :

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
            "cmd /c start \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe\" --headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf javaGen.pdf  file:///C:/Users/User/Desktop/template/template2.html");
```

And I got :

```
windows can't find --headless
```

***EDIT 2 ***

I tried this command :

```
pb.command(new String[] { "cd \"Program Files (x86)\"", "cd Google\\Chrome\\Application\\",
            "chrome.exe --headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf javaGen.pdf  file:///C:/Users/User/Desktop/template/template2.html" });
    pb.start();
```

And I got :

```
Cannot run program "cd "Program Files (x86)"": CreateProcess error=2, File not found
```

Comment: have you tried `"cmd /c start \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe\" --headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf javaGen.pdf  file:///C:/Users/User/Desktop/template/template2.html"`?

Comment: I just tried it and I got the same result

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Executing another application from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468987/executing-another-application-from-java)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ProcessBuilder cannot run bat file with spaces in path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25377355/processbuilder-cannot-run-bat-file-with-spaces-in-path)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run a program with cmd you only need `cmd /c %programname%`, but you added `start` which caused the problem.

Change your ProcessBuilder to:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(
            "cmd", "/c", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe", "--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--print-to-pdf", "javaGen.pdf",  "file:///C:/Users/User/Desktop/template/template2.html");
pb.start();
```